# Default values were not showing in the html page (Flask Forms)?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, constructor, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am getting data from the database get_row = PolicyCheck.query.filter_by(id=1).first()

class EditPasswordPolicyForm(FlaskForm):

```
greater = IntegerField('greater')
lesser = IntegerField('lesser')
special = BooleanField('special')
upper = BooleanField('upper')
lower = BooleanField('lower')
digit = BooleanField('digit')
update = SubmitField('update')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EditPasswordPolicyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    get_row = PolicyCheck.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    self.greater.default = get_row.greaterthan
    self.lesser.default = get_row.lessthan
    self.special.default = get_row.specialChar
    self.upper.default = get_row.isupper
    self.lower.default = get_row.islower
    self.digit.default = get_row.isdigit
```

The values are getting updated for whatever the value I fill in the form and submit, but all the form fields are blank by default. I want to show the latest updated data from the database in the form fields as default values. When I fill the form and submit It should get refreshed by the latest updated value as default values and should not be blank.

Comment: You can make a new html template for that saying for example, formupdate.html with render_field functions

Answer (score 0):

```py
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EditPasswordPolicyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    get_row = PolicyCheck.query.filter_by(id=1).first()
    self.greater.data = get_row.greaterthan
    self.lesser.data = get_row.lessthan
    self.special.data = get_row.specialChar
    self.upper.data = get_row.isupper
    self.lower.data = get_row.islower
    self.digit.data = get_row.isdigit
```

Maybe it will work.